# Sample and rbinom generating disparate results?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, simulation

I am sure I am just misunderstanding this but rbinom and sample seem to be generating disparate results and I am not sure why. I am trying to create a categorical factor with a balanced third in each levels (so .33 get 0, .33 get 1, .33 get 2).

If I attempt to sample evenly 1/3 from rbinom(), I get uneven distributions:

```
table(rbinom(100,2,c(.33,.33,.33)))
 0  1  2 
47 42 11 
 0  1  2 
49 41 10
 0  1  2 
46 40 14 
 0  1  2 
45 43 12 
 0  1  2 
46 38 16
```

The third level is not getting many successes and I am not sure why.

If I do the same thing for the sample() function, I get more satisfactory results.

```
table(sample(c(1,2,3),100,replace = T,prob = c(.33,.33,.33)))
 1  2  3 
32 32 36 
 1  2  3 
39 33 28 
 1  2  3 
30 41 29 
 1  2  3 
33 34 33 
1  2  3 
36 25 39 
1  2  3 
39 31 30
```

Here, each level (1, 2, and 3) is getting around 33% of successes which is what I wanted.

How do I get rbinom() to do the same thing, distributing successes evenly across 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: You want the the multinomial, not the binomial distribution. Try `rmultinom(5, 100, c(.33,.33,.33))`.

Comment: for rbinom, the probability of getting a 2 is from a size 2 with success of 0.33 is 0.1089. Hence 11% of the time you will get a 2. and that is exactly what you have. `dbinom` is not same as discrete uniform. You should use `rmultinom` as suggested or use `sample` as you are doing so far

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, your code does not do what you want it to do. First, many of R's functions vectorized the passed parameter values, in case of your code `rbinom(100,2,c(.33,.33,.33))` is the same as `rbinom(100,2,.33)`, or `rbinom(100,2,c(.33,.33))`, or `rbinom(100,2,rep(.33, 100))` because all the values provided to `prob` are the same, if they differed, it'd cycle through them until  drawing the intended 100 samples.

The code itself produces draws from a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with sample `size=2`, so you are independently tossing a biased coin with `prob=0.33` two times. Your second snippet draws each of the values in `c(1,2,3)` with an equal probability of 0.33. So the first code would produce the result 2 with probability `0.33 * 0.33 = 0.1089` (two independent [coin throws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)), while the second the result 3 with a probability of 0.33 (you roll a [three-sided dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution)). In the first case, the probability distribution is

$$
\Pr(X=k) = {2 \choose k} \, 0.33^k \,0.66^{2-k}
$$

while in the second case, it's just $\Pr(X=k) = 0.33$. They *are not* the same.

This is what you observe if you run the code.

```r
> n <- 1000000
> table(rbinom(n, 2, .33)) / n

       0        1        2 
0.448398 0.443002 0.108600 
> table(rbinom(n, 2, c(.33,.33,.33))) / n

       0        1        2 
0.449160 0.441886 0.108954 
> table(sample(c(1,2,3), n, replace = T, prob = c(.33,.33,.33))) / n

       1        2        3 
0.333505 0.332922 0.333573
```

You can achieve the same result as when using `rbinom` with `sample` if you use this unnecessarily slow code:

```
> table(replicate(n, sum(sample(c(0, 1), size=2, replace=T, prob=c(.66,.33))))) / n

       0        1        2 
0.444294 0.444688 0.111018
```

Answer (score 5):

When calling

```
rbinom(100,2,c(a,b,c))
```

the outcome is equivalent to

```
c(rbinom(2,a),rbinom(2,b),rbinom(2,c),rbinom(2,a),rbinom(2,b),...)
```